# Using SELECT on 2 or more tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

Consider the following database:

Browsers table:

```
id | name        | description                     | stuff different from cars table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Chrome      | Some description
 2 | Firefox     | Some other description
 3 | Vivaldi     | Even more description
```

Cars table:

```
id | name        | description                      | stuff different from browsers table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Hyundai     | Some korean description
 2 | Ford        | Some ford ther description
 3 | Ferrari     | Even ferrari more description
```

The output that I need to get in PHP is 6 objects with an id, a name and a description. Can I do that with a `join` keyword? If so... How, I've been quietly researching for hours. Or maybe a different approach?

If I were to make a table of the output data I need to get, that would be:

```
id | name        | description                   
------------------------------------------------
 1 | Hyundai     | Some korean description
 2 | Ford        | Some ford ther description
 3 | Ferrari     | Even ferrari more description
 1 | Chrome      | Some description
 2 | Firefox     | Some other description
 3 | Vivaldi     | Even more description
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a usecase for a `join`. Since you want to have rows from both tables *one after the other*, not side by side, you should use a `union all`:

```
SELECT id, name, description
FROM   browsers
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, description
FROM   cars
```

Comment: can this be use as SELECT * FROM browsers UNION ALL SELECT * FROM cars? Considering the different table columns?

Comment: @MerdescuR. If they have the same number of columns with the same types, in the same order (regardless of their names) - yes. If not, you can't - both queries must have the same number and types of columns.

Comment: @MerdescuR. Different column name should be not working UNION ALL